# Is there a way to use wildcards in css id tag

Tags: css, css-selectors

assuming i have few items with similar ids:

```
<input class="a" id="id_1"/>
<input class="a" id="id_2"/>
```

i would like to set in my css file something like:

```
#id_*{width = 100%;}
```

is there a way i can do that?
i've tried something like:

```
input[id^='id_']{width:200px;}
```

but that didnt worked out......

And its need to work on IE :(

EDIT: nedd to work on IE8....

EDIT:

```
<input tabIndex="1690" class="form" id="cust_1_NUM_OBJ_5-00461" dataFld="cust_1_NUM_OBJ_5-00461" dataSrc="#FIELDVALUES" style="text-align: right; height: 20px;" onkeypress="validateNumberChar(this)" onfocus="resetGFocusField('cust_1_NUM_OBJ_5-00461');" onblur="validateChangedNumber(this);" onbeforedeactivate="onbeforedeactivateLookup(this);" type="text" size="20" maxLength="55" datatype="number" numbertype="24,6" valueFieldID="null" tabStop="true" value="1"/>
```

and CSS:

```
input[id^='cust_1_NUM_OBJ_5-0046']{width:200px;}
```

[image: Without style]

[image: Witj style]

Comment: 100% or 200px doesnt matter :)

Answer (score 51):

`input[id^='id_']{width:200px;}` should work. It certainly does in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jYZnX/

EDIT: Also, to show that it doesn't pick an input without an id beginning `'id_'`:

http://jsfiddle.net/jYZnX/1/

EDIT 2: As your Document Mode seems to be set to *Quirks* this will cause issues with the css selector. Set your doc type correctly, eg using `<!DOCTYPE HTML>`. This will need access to the original code for the web pages though, so without that you will be in a spot of bother.

Comment: I know it work in general but not on Internet Explorer.
Im looking for the IE version of ^=

Comment: It works in IE too. Open that page in IE and you will see it does work.

Comment: It completely matters what browser you use. I can make something that won't show correctly in IE, example using css3. Check out http://jsfiddle.net/czeQH/ and you'll see the shadow shows in FF and Chrome, and IE9, but not IE8 or earlier. It doesn't simulate it is a correct representation in the browser you open it in.

Comment: @anothershrubery Sorry, you where right. But 'input[id^="'id_']{width:200px;}' doesnt seem to work on IE8.... is there a version for IE8 of ^=?

Comment: It does! I am using IE8 right now and it is working! If you look at http://jsfiddle.net/jYZnX/1/ can you not see 2 input boxes which are longer than the other?

Comment: I do but somehow in my web it doesnt eventhough i see in the devTool of IE that he recognized it.....

Comment: You might need to give us a link to the page or at least the full code to have a look then because it definitely should work.

Comment: i cannot give a link since its a webapp on local server but i added some code.

Comment: Again that is still working. http://jsfiddle.net/H9Buv/ You can change the width and the input will change width. You can also change the id to `cust_1`, or similar, and it will still work. Can you show a screenshot of the problem?

Comment: Everything seems to be fine there. It is working in FF and Chrome?

Comment: The webapp doesnt support FF and Chrome only IE>5.5

Comment: Do me a favour, using the IE dev tool, change the value for width to 300px and see if the width changes. What width are the other input components?

Comment: When i use the IE dev tool nothing changes but if in the CSS file i put #<name>{width:200px;} its working fine

Comment: In that case I can't really help any further without seeing a copy of the code. Everything looks like it should work fine.

Comment: You shouldn't have to, I'm sure there is some minor problem that could be easily fixed but, as I say, it would only be possible if I had a look at the code. If you have to you may need to hard code, if you can't add classes to the markup, but try to look for a solution beforehand.

Comment: What does the clientWidth attribute means? 
I looked at the read only attributes and it set to 111...

Comment: The clientWidth is just reporting what width the object is. You can't change this without the usual methods of `width`, which is where the problem is here. It is only used via javascript.

Answer (score 9):

The selector you used (`^`), works correctly in IE:

```
input[id^='id'] {
    background: red;
}
```

And here is the result:

#### IE7

[image]

---

#### IE8

[image]

---

#### IE9

[image]

---

#### IE10

[image]

---

As I saw in your pictures, your IE is rendering your page with **Quirks Mode**.
Maybe you have no doctype or wrong doctype at your page. Make your doctype valid as below:

```
<!doctype html>
```

Comment: Good spot with the Quirks Mode. That will definitely cause problems.

Comment: Just putting it out there that `^=` is a level 3 selector and [will not work](http://caniuse.com/#search=css3%20se) on versions of IE lower than 9.

Answer (score 8):

My answer is quite general and never directly related to the question because this is already very old and so far solved by other answers on this page.

---

**The first part of this answer is dry theory which is useful to understand the options.

The second part is an example for usage of this theory.**

---

**1) ATTRIBUTE SELCTORS**

**[Substring matching attribute selectors](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#attribute-substrings):**

`[att^=val]`
Represents an element with the att attribute whose value begins with the prefix "val". If "val" is the empty string then the selector does not represent anything.

`[att$=val]`
Represents an element with the att attribute whose value ends with the suffix "val". If "val" is the empty string then the selector does not represent anything.

`[att*=val]`
Represents an element with the att attribute whose value contains at least one instance of the substring "val". If "val" is the empty string then the selector does not represent anything.

Additionally there are still more selectors, in the specification they are sorted in the chapter **[Attribute presence and value selectors](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#attribute-representation)**:

`[att]`
Represents an element with the att attribute, whatever the value of the attribute.

`[att=val]`
Represents an element with the att attribute whose value is exactly "val".

`[att~=val]`
Represents an element with the att attribute whose value is a whitespace-separated list of words, one of which is exactly "val". If "val" contains whitespace, it will never represent anything (since the words are separated by spaces). Also if "val" is the empty string, it will never represent anything.

`[att|=val]`
Represents an element with the att attribute, its value either being exactly "val" or beginning with "val" immediately followed by "-" (U+002D).

---

**2) EXAMPLE HOW TO SELECT SEVERAL THINGS ON A PAGE DEPENDING ON AN EVENT**

Wildcards are especially then useful when an event is triggered like that a page is visited with a special hash-tag. For a completely static page in contrast they are also useful but still could be noted different, even it would be more CSS-code.

Assume a page is visited with the hash-tag `action`, so the URL would look like this:

```
https://example.com/index.html#action
```

While only one id is triggered like that we can use it to note a whole stack of related actions in CSS, we just have to enclose the whole area where something shall happen in an element with the id `action`:

```css
/* all div-elements which are direct child of element with class `wrapper` are hidden: */

.wrapper>div {
  display: none;
}


/* following line addresses all elements inside element with the id "action"
   where the id is starting with "action_". This is only triggered when the
   URL with hashtag "action" is called, because of usage of ":target":
*/

#action:target [id^="action_"] {
  display: block;
}


/* following line addresses all elements inside element with the id "amother-action"
   where the class is "another-action". This is only triggered when the
   URL with hashtag "another-action" is called, because of usage of ":target".
   This example shows that we never need ids but can use classes too:
*/

#another-action:target .another-action {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="action">
  <div id="another-action">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <!-- this small menu is always shown as it's an unordered list and no div: -->
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">No Action / Reset</a></li>
        <li><a href="#action">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#another-action">Another Action</a></li>
      </ul>
      <!-- The following div-elements are by default hidden and
           only shown when some event is triggered: -->
      <div id="action_1" class="another-action">
        <!-- this is on both actions shown as the div has an id starting
               with "action" and also a class "another-action" -->
        Hello
      </div>
      <div id="action_2">
        <!-- this is above only triggered by the CSS-rule 
               #action:target [id^="action_"] -->
        World!
      </div>
      <div class="another-action">
        <!-- This is above only triggered by the CSS-rule
               #another-action:target .another-action -->
        Everybody!
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The different results are these:

1. When the page is called without any hash, only the menu is shown:

> - Action
> - Another Action

2. When the page is called with the hash `action`, below the menu can be seen:

> Hello
> World!

3. When the page is called with the hash `another-action`, below the menu can be seen this instead:

> Hello
> Everybody!

Like this we can mix much content where each division is only shown in special cases.
Mixing several ids and classes does only work if the elements with the ids are enclosing the elements with content and select-able properties. In my example above you can see that everything in HTML is written between `<div id="action"><div id="another-action">` and `</div></div>`, like this every used event can optionally trigger everything in the content between.

Naturally it's possible by CSS to use this method for other effects too. Hiding or showing the elements is only a simple example but you could change colors, start CSS-animations and do many other things by CSS.

---

**Keep care that you don't publish any confidential things in any of those elements, because this CSS-solution is no security but only for distinguishing cases for visual display.
Any things you hide or show like this are always visible in the HTML-source.**

Answer (score 1):

Given a three-column table with 200 rows and each row having an individual id like this row:

```
<tr id="row_177">
 <td><a class="btn" href="..">Link1</a></td>
 <td><a href="pdfName.pdf" target="_blank">Name of PDF File</a></td>
 <td><select class="pdf_sel">
    <option value=""> ---- </option>
    <option>Crowell, Thomas</option> 
    </select>
 </td>
</tr>
```

and given that you want to vertically center the content in each td, then the following css wildcard will cause the content of each td to be centered vertically** (I'm sure you could also use this to adjust width):

```
tr[id^='row_'] > td {
  vertical-align:middle
}
```

** One caveat - the third column in the table contains a Select in each td.  While the anchor button in the first column and the text anchor in the second column are centered vertically in each td by using the above css, the Select in the third column does not respond to this css for some reason - but there is a fix. The following css will cause the Select elements to be properly centered vertically:

```
tr[id^='pdfrow_'] > td > select {
margin-top:5px;
margin-bottom:5px
}
```

Comment: `vertical-align` refers to lines and `line-height`. Line-height exists related to select too, but it's inside the element and never includes the whole element itself.

Answer (score -1):

That is precisely what classes are for. What you want is:

```
.a { width: 100% }
```

Comment: these arent all the instances of class a in genral and i dont want to effect all.

Comment: Why not apply classes to those that you want to affect?

Comment: I dont want to manipulate the web design for styleing and I dont have the code who build the website.

Comment: Create a new class then. By definition, if all of your `id_*`s behave the same, they are part of the same class (speaking in English terms, not CSS), so you can create a CSS class for that behaviour. If `a` is not good, create a new one `<input class="a newClass" id="id_2"/>`

Comment: BUT, there are times that you don't have control over the classes or ids that get added after the fact. HTML Email, for instance. Zimbra will add their own OBJECT class and OBJ_PREFIX_DWTnnn ids to items that it thinks are dates, and then mangle your styles to their designs. Annoying as heck! Have added a style overide (with !important) to the CLASS's text-decoration, color and cursor) and to the ID using span[id^='OBJ_PREFIX']{}. Either solution works in Chrome, neither have any affect in IE (Windows 7, latest versions as of this date).